# No ads showing admob in live iOS add

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

I used adMob in my iOS app. But when i test the app it shows the test ads in the simulator, but when i try to get ads on my device (Its not a developer device) then i don't get any ads. When i use my developer device i get "no ads to show". I have setup adMob used the key.

Here is my code:

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad 
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self datoUgeNummer];
```

`// Initialize the banner at the bottom of the screen.
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             self.view.frame.size.height -
                             CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);

// Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin];

// Note: Edit SampleConstants.h to provide a definition for kSampleAdUnitID before compiling.
self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-4641309369865580/3940179951";
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
self.adBanner.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
[self.adBanner loadRequest:[self request]];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    _adBanner.delegate = nil;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

#pragma mark GADRequest generation

-(GADRequest *)request {
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

// Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for the simulator as well as any devices
// you want to receive test ads.
//request.testDevices = @[
                        // TODO: Add your device/simulator test identifiers here. Your device identifier is printed to
                        // the console when the app is launched.
            //            GAD_SIMULATOR_ID
              //          ];
return request;
}

#pragma mark GADBannerViewDelegate implementation

// We've received an ad successfully.
-(void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"Received ad successfully");
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error   {
NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}`

Do i also need Google Analytics to get adMob working ?

I hope you understand my english and can help me! :)

Comment: hi~ I encountered this problem too, have you solved it?

Comment: I have a similar problem - "No ad to show" error for a new game for LIVE ads, but test ads work fine. Did you find a solution? I have posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65237868/admob-on-ios-no-ad-to-show