# AdMob on iOS - No ad to show

Tags: ios, admob

I have had AdMob working fine with test ads for the last 6 months on a new iOS game. Now I want to release it, I switch to using the live AdUnitIds that I have setup in Admob, but it fails on all iOS devices with this error:

> Request Error: 1 No ad to show.

Occurring here:

```
public override void DidFailToReceiveAd(Interstitial sender, RequestError error)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(“DidFailToReceiveAd  error={0}", error);
}
```

I am using banner and interstitial ads and get the same error for both.

I have two other games with AdMob all working fine.

Some observations and thoughts:

1. Interestingly, if I change the BundleID of my new game to one of my other games, the live ads work fine (ie using the exact same code and the new AdUnitIDs), so it can't be problem with my code or the AdUnitIDs. For some reason it doesn’t like my games BundleID.
2. Is it because the new game is not live in the App Store yet (it’s Pending Developer Release)? I don’t think so as live ads certainly used to work before release.
3. My new app is not “linked” to AdMob (you can’t link it until it’s Live), so is it related to that? Again I don’t think so as Linking didn't used to make any difference (with my two other games over the last two years)
4. I can see in my AdMob account there are hundreds of "Requests" but no "Impressions" (apart from the handful I got when I changed the BundleID to my other game as I mentioned above).

So I am stuck waiting to release this new game. Maybe releasing it will start the Ads working? But if not, my game will be shooting up the charts while I don’t get any revenue!

Has someone else had the same problem and then maybe it started working by itself after 7 days or 30 days? Or if they had to create a totally new app with different BundleId or if they gave up and used a different ad supplier?

(Also it seems impossible to contact AdMob support, there's no email or phone and I have tried posting on their support forum, but no joy, so I am really stuck! Does anyone know any way to contact AdMob support?)

Comment: error code 1 means. Invalid Ad Id. Check your Ad ID ( its not app id). I would simply create a new Ad ID and try again https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en

Comment: Yea, I have check the ID - it's correct. In iOS error 1 is not invalid Ad Id, it says "No ad to show". And I have tried a new AdUnitId, on my second one now but both don't work. And interestingly it DOES work OK if I use my other game's BundleID (a game that is 2 years old in the App Store), I do get impressions, so the ID is setup correctly.

Comment: Can you try resetting advertising identifier and load app again? If device has ios14+ then (go to settings, privacy, tracking and turn off) and clear app cache and allow app tracking

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I printed the IDFA and then turned tracking off and then back on and it did indeed change the IDFA, but still I get the "No ad to show." error. I have tried it on 4 different iPhones/iPads anyway (all different IDFAs), so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: give a try with this - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10159602

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with my app... Test ID works fine on debug! My app is currently on the app store and no ad is showing

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately that's in version 7.68.0 and I'm stuck on version 7.66.0 for now as I'm using Xamarin and the Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds package is only at 7.66.0.

Comment: @idenardi, that's interesting that even when in the App Store it's not working. I'm still waiting for ads to work before releasing mine and was wondering if releasing it would make it work. Mine has not been working for 9 days now, how long has it been for you?

Comment: @idenardi, there are others with the same problem in this AdMob support group, so you might want to post there too: https://support.google.com/admob/thread/86962136?hl=en

Comment: @Bbx I'm also using Xamarin... maybe the bug is in Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds package. I'll try to downgrade the version

Comment: Well I've tried with last version of Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds 7.57 and got the same problem

Comment: @idenardi Yea, I have 2 other apps working perfectly fine with the exact same code as my new app. So it's not to do with the Xamarin MobileAds version - my current theory is it's a Google AdMob problem blocking certain Apps (certain app BundleIds) for some reason, maybe because they are new, or maybe they don't have enough traffic or something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65303256/14414215 Check this answer.

Comment: @myjunk Thanks. that's very interesting.

Answer (score 8):

So ads are finally working!

I eventually took the step of releasing my new game (I used manual release in the App Store and had been waiting 10 days but no ads showed).

18 hours after appearing in the App Store, ads started working.

More thoughts and observations:

1. I did not link AdMob to the App Store (I still haven’t), but interestingly my game does now appear in AdMobs search, so I can link it, so linking is not required.
2. So what actually caused ads to start working? It’s either:

> A) AdMob detect the app is actually in the App Store.

> B) The game got 5 or so new people using it, so ads were requested from a few different IP addresses)and this triggers AdMob to serve ads.

> C) It takes 10 days after  switching from test ads to Live for ads to work

My theory is it’s A (especially as I can see Disc Drop in Admob’s search).

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem before, my app is also IOS. and I solved this problem now.
If your code is correct(you can show the test AD on you device), **all you need is wait.** AdMob will take some time for review you application.In my case, It took two days for review my APP and then I got the impressions.