# After a lot of time, admob banners never started showing. Only test banners work

Tags: admob

I'm add google admob on my ios app.
I'm using Native Advanced banners.
So test banners works perfect
[working native banner with test id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz5mr.jpg)
this test banner have id ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511

But when i change banner id for my created - it become empty
[empty not working banner with my id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjNLU.jpg)

What i have done:

1. Register my admob account & connect it with my firebase project.
2. Approve my payment data on admob & get mail thats everything ok.
3. Add Admob id on my plist project file.

It's looks like this

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-***********~**********</string>
```

A week has passed, but unfortunately my banners remain empty.
My app hasn't been published yet. I cannot send it for review team with empty banners. It will not be allowed with this issue.

What I haven’t done yet is

1. I haven’t set up mediation.

Maybe this is the case? I could not find information on whether this is really necessary or not.
I also note that for the duration of the tests, I registered the application in another admob account and before launching, I decided to transfer everything to a new account and indicated the bundle id the same as indicated during registration on the first test account.
Maybe that's the case?
Please help to solve the problem. I read that after setting up the banners should start showing after a few hours, unfortunately much more time has passed..

Answer (score 3):

It was similar issue as mine.  But as most SO answers will tell you. Likely it’s not you. It’s google.

I registered my account about 1+ month ago. Integrated it into the project and nothing worked except test ads. 2 weeks later. Fed up I deleted and regenerated a new app id but still didn’t work.

So, I finished the project. Uploaded to the App Store. Still didn’t work. (After it was in the App Store, I tried linking the app to AdMob but couldn’t. Can’t find my app in AdMob)

So waited. About 10days after publishing in App Store, it finally appeared in AdMob and I could link my app (In AdMob console) to App Store link.

After that, ads started to work.

YMMV but that’s my story. Google just hadn’t indexed my app.

Comment: Yes, i I also think that the application should be published and then the advertisement will work. But think, apple review team will not allow an app with an empty banner. What to do then? :)  first have to publish without ad units, then link the application with a link to the apple store, insert ad units and release an update with them?

Comment: Oh. I just followed the way google suggested. Create the banner but make it hidden. Then use a callback to enable the banner when an ad is received. 

Check out google docs in Admob. I just followed the directions. Hence, when I linked the app in Admob to App Store. Ads just show up without needing a new app update.

Comment: func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
  print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
}

Comment: Interesting , as I have same situation but not dare publish without ads. So you had it available in the App Store with no ads for 10 days and when you finally managed to link it in AdMob console, it started working? How long after linking it, did ads appear?

Comment: @Bbx I can’t recall but couple hours I think. You can use the adviewdidreceive function and I hide the banner once an ad is received.